# missbehaviour of "OR" in python

Tags: python, canopy

Hy... I'm just learning python. And I have made a program like this :

```
guess = raw_input("please input something...");
while (guess != 'h'):
    guess = raw_input("pleae input something again....");
    print(guess);

print("Thanks...");
```

Well... Above program is running well. But when I put "OR" after guess != 'h' like this :

```
guess = raw_input("please input something...");
while (guess != 'h') or (guess != 't'):
    guess = raw_input("pleae input something again....");
    print(guess);

print("Thanks...");
```

Above program is running forever in while loop. What's happening there ? I thought the loop will be ended after I input either h or t

Comment: When `guess` is `h` it obviously won't be `t`; as one of the condition to continue is `guess != 't'`, it satisfies the condition to continue the loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your condition always holds:

```
(guess != 'h') or (guess != 't')
```

Is always true (if one part is not true it implies the other one is).

If you use [De-Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) here you get something a bit more obvious:

```
not (guess == 'n' and guess == 't')
```

This is obviously **always** true (`guess` can only be one thing).

You probably want:

```
(guess != 'h') and (guess != 't')
```

Or better yet:

```
while guess not in 'ht':
```

Comment: Thanks, I missunderstood it... :)

Answer (score 5):

```
while (guess != 'h') or (guess != 't')
```

This line basically says : repeat the loop if my input is not 'h' or my input is not 't'. Since the console input can't be both 'h' and 't at the same time, the loop will repeat forever. Are you sure you're not looking for `while guess != 'h' and guess != 't'` or `while not (guess == 'h' or guess == 't')` (both of them are identical from a logical standpoint) ?

Answer (score 2):

That's not misbehaviour; it's how boolean logic works in all languages. For this kind of comparison you need to use `and`.